# Android AdMob error

Tags: android, admob

Here's my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<com.google.ads.AdView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a151fe0d3b33c23" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here's my java code:

```
package com.asdf.asdf.asdf;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asdf.asdf.asdf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.asdf.asdf.asdf.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

and I have downloaded the latest AdMob SDK from the AdMob official website.
I have linked my AdMob SDK with my project by clicking on:

`properties > libraries > add external JARs` and then I browsed for that jar..

In the graphical layout window when I open the XML file, it shows a little BANNER with **"Ads by Google"** in the AdView.

but then when I run it, it comes: "Unfortunately, MainActivity has stopped"

By the way, MainActivity is my activity's name.

please help and tell me where I'm going wrong...

by the way, I dpnt know how much this helps, by when I check my AdMob account, it tells me, 0 requests for my app...